# Copying large folders remotely

Tags: windows, network-share, remote

I have this network shares on a Windows 7 host:

- `D` (SATA HDD1 D:)
- `E` (SATA HDD2 E:)

They are mounted remotely as 'D' and 'E'.

Network speed is 100mbps Cat-5. (max transfer speed is ~ 1.25Mbytes/s)

Remotely, when I copy a large folder from **D** to **E** shares (*"theorically"* from one HDD to another) it is faster than the network speed but way slow than if I  copy the files locally.

- Actual network copy speed: **~ 1.25Mb/s**. (maximum)
- Local speed HDD-to-HDD copy speed: **~ 110Mb/s**. (SATA speed)
- Copying files remotely from mount points **D** to **E**: **~ 50Mb/s**

The copy comand is remote but **the source and destination are local to each other**. How can I increase the transfer speed in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Run the copy command on the remote machine. Either by logging in yourself or with powershell script which logs in and copies needed files/directories.

Comment: It is a regular users scenario. They know copy and paste. but nothing about a console.